# Grafico Plotly en ventana de Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, plotly

¿ como ingresar un grafico creado en plotly pero que se vea dentro de una ventana de tkinter ?

Por ejemplo el siguiente grafico:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Datos de ejemplo
x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
y = [10, 20, 15, 12]

# Crear una figura de barras con Plotly
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(x=x, y=y))

# Personalizar el diseño del gráfico
fig.update_layout(title='Gráfico de barras',
                  xaxis_title='Eje X',
                  yaxis_title='Eje Y')

# Mostrar el gráfico
fig.show()
```